# What is the best practice for the max length of an unminified javascript file before refactoring?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

With the rise of nodeJs and the ever more powerful JavaScript frameworks, I find myself writing a lot more JavaScript these days.   One question that crosses my mind frequently is when is a JavaScript file so large that I should refactor that JavaScript file into two different JavaScript files (and often into separate objects/services).

I've spent a fair amount of time studying refactoring so I know that there are a lot of issues that go into such a decision, but I am just wondering what the best practice rule of thumb is for the max length on an unminified JavaScript file?

I know that typically JavaScript files are bundled and minified in different ways, I'm only talking about when coding JavaScript before minification.  Also I know there are general best practices about code file length, but I was curious what the best practice is for JavaScript specifically rather than the general case.

An answer in terms of line numbers would be nice.

What is the best practice for the length of a JavaScript code file?

Comment: Personally I'd only think of refactoring for usability.  For example, if I'd started a project a while ago and found myself needing to reuse something more than expected.  I'd shove that off into a library or plugin type chunk of code.  Architecture means less and less each day, as far as performance goes.  I prefer structured code for my own sake, rather than that of the end user.  That's just me though, and I'll probably get slated for saying it :p

Comment: @Archer Sure, but at some point a javascript file is just too big for usability's sake even if it makes sense as a single unit conceptionally.  Having to scroll over huge amounts of code eventually reduces productivity excessively, I'm wondering what people feel is that point in terms of lines of code.

Comment: That's why I said I prefer to structure code for my own sake, rather than anything to do with performance (download speed, browser caching etc.).  If you're coding OO JavaScript then just use the same coding style you would for any other OO language.  A file per class (or namespace).  This is a _very_ subjective question and I hope you get some more people commenting as I'd like to see what others think, but at the end of the day I just do what suits me and the project I'm on at that time.